# Install PyNSource in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python-2.7

How can i Install **PyNSource** in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (the python version is 2.7)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to download it an run it from sources:

http://pynsource.googlecode.com/files/pyNsource-1.61-src.zip

Extract the zip file and go to the `pyNsource-1.61-src` folder to change the `rungui.sh` mode bits:

```
chmod +x ./rungui.sh
```

Install the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python-configobj python-wxgtk2.8
```

An just run the above script to start PyNsource GUI:

[image]